# List of strings to string

Tags: c#, string, list, type-conversion

I have a list of strings:

```
List<string[]> myList
```

I want to convert it to a string separated by ",".
I know how to convert List myList but not what i need..
I tried

```
String.Join(", ", myList.ToArray());
```

But i won't work for string[]

I tried to search the internet for solutions but could not found one...
I know i can do it with foreach but im looking for one line solution, mostly to learn more advanced coding.

Thank you!

Comment: `.SelectMany` could be your friend.

Comment: One line doesn't necessarily mean advance coding

Comment: @Izzy I know, i mean like Daniel said, i wanted to find a function like SelectMany

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok sir. done :)

Comment: Looking forward the next super complicated question like "List of ints to string`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) to flatten your `List<string[]>`:

```
string.Join(", ", myList.SelectMany(x => x));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Join twice.

```
String.Join(", ", myList.Select(arr => "{" + String.Join(", ", arr) + "}"));
```

As mentioned by @TimSchmelter use this approach when you want to use different delimiters for each group. so you can join inner array by something like `,` and the outer list by `/` or any thing you prefer. also you can use braces to make it look better.

BTW if delimiters are same use the approach given by @YuvalItzchakov

Comment: Working but why do you use `", "` and `","`, so one time with space and one time without? OP hasn't mentioned that. This approach would be fine if that was a requirement, otherwise `SelectMany` is better.